# Clearing the echo history

Tags: bash, function, return, echo

I have a bash script that calls a function which returns a value.  I have included the scripts below:

Script

```
source ./utilities/function1.sh
result=$(Function1)
echo "Result: $result"
```

Function1

```
function Function1 {
    echo "Inside Function: Function1"

cat <<EOF
this is the result
EOF
}
```

I want to be able to echo to the console within the function and return only the value I want, not including the messages that were echoed to the console, but when I run the script the following is returned:

```
Result: Inside Function: Func1
this is the result
```

Is this the best way to return a value from a bash function or is there a way I can echo to the console and return a value without the content of the echo commands from the function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't return values from functions in a shell script, you can however set values to be used somewhere else in your code. Check https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/return-values-bash-functions on how to overcome that.
What are you actually trying to do? Depending on what you want to achieve it might be better to create the functionality as a Python script which will give you return-from-function functionality and much, much more.

Comment: `echo "Inside Function: Function1" >&2`?

Comment: Some more updated info on working around the return value problem in Bash: https://linuxhint.com/return-string-bash-functions/ 
But again, spend some time trying to code the same functionality in Python, it's a whole lot more fun! But if you really, really want to, this might help: ```function Function1 {
    echo "Inside Function: Function1"
cat <<EOF
this is the result
EOF
val="something"
}

val=""
Function1
echo "val: "$val```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to do what you want. two simple ones are:

Use STDERR to echo to the console and capture STDOUT in your script. By default, STDOUT is on File Descriptor 1 and STDERR is on File Descriptor 2:

```
function myFunction() {
  echo "This goes to STDOUT" >&1  # '>&1' is the default, so can be left out.
  echo "This goes to STDERR" >&2
}

result=$(myFunction)
echo ${result}
```

Use a variable to return a string to the caller:

```
function myFunction() {
  echo "This goes to STDOUT"
  result="This goes into the variable"
}

declare    result="" # Has global scope. Can be modified from anywhere.
myFunction
echo ${result}
```

Global scope variables are not good programming practice, but are a necessary evil in bash scripting.